# Stash content depending on SSL / https

Tags: stash, ssl

How can i stash content globally depending on https or http scheme?

One way is to store it under a context,
but then i have to change all stash set and get tags site-wide to work with a context parameter

```
{exp:stash:context name="{IS_SSL}"}

{exp:stash:set_list name="news" 
  save="yes" replace="no" refresh="30" context="@"
}
{stash:item_link}http://example.com{/stash:item_link}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Without setting this context, the value would be stored once for 30 minutes, and served to everyone regardless of http scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to ask is, do you really need to? Your links could just be protocol relative:

{stash:item_link}//example.com{/stash:item_link}

If that's not the issue then you could create a global prefix in your config using Stash's config variable `stash_var_prefix`:

```
$config['stash_var_prefix'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ? 'ssl:' : 'nonssl:';
```

(Note that a prefix followed by colon `:` is the same result as specifying a `context=""` on each tag individually.)

Comment: In the end we ended up just serving https only. In the main index.php redirect if needed. Flushed the stash cache once, and only https content is served and cached now